# Error with len() function or something else?

Tags: python

So I've been trying to get my program to loop through this pke equation with only the `e` changing 15 times into a list. I thought I had it solved but in my print statement instead of `len` just printing a single number for each exponent it's lopping through and printing a number for every unique number it has. I'm having trouble with seeing where I'm going wrong. My program is this:

```
def greatest_common_divisor(a_int, b_int):
    if a_int > b_int:
        dividend = a_int
        divisor = b_int
    else: # b >= a
        dividend = b_int
        divisor = a_int
    remainder = dividend % divisor
    quotient = dividend // divisor
    while remainder != 0:
        dividend = divisor
        divisor = remainder
        remainder = dividend % divisor
        quotient = dividend // divisor
    return divisor # which is the gcd

p =5
q = 7
n = p*q
header = ["p","q","n","e","diminished","gcd","unique remainders","max remainders"]
print(header)

for e in range(12,27):
unique_remainders_list = []
for x in range(1,(n+1)):
    y = x**e % n
    diminished = (p - 1)*(q - 1)
    gcd = greatest_common_divisor(e, diminished)
    max_uni_val = n-1
    if not (y in unique_remainders_list):
        unique_remainders_list.append(y)
        print("{:>2} {:>4} {:>6} {:>4} {:>10} {:>9} {:>10} {:>16}".\
    format(p,q,n,e,diminished,gcd,len(unique_remainders_list),max_uni_val, end = ' '))
```

Example of print:

```
 ['p', 'q', 'n', 'e', 'diminished', 'gcd', 'unique remainders', 'max remainders']
   5    7     35   12         24        12          1               34
   5    7     35   12         24        12          2               34
   5    7     35   12         24        12          3               34
   5    7     35   12         24        12          4               34
   5    7     35   13         24         1          1               34
   5    7     35   13         24         1          2               34
   5    7     35   13         24         1          3               34
   5    7     35   13         24         1          4               34
   5    7     35   13         24         1          5               34
   5    7     35   13         24         1          6               34
   5    7     35   13         24         1          7               34
   5    7     35   13         24         1          8               34
```

So I think I'm having trouble with the range of e in the end, I'm just not sure where.

Comment: I need a list of the function but with 15 different integers and the unique remainder to simple print only the number of of the unique rmainders for that change so I end up with a row of 15.

Comment: use `unique_remainders_list = set();`. When you add numbers to it, it will all be unique and no duplicates. See if it becomes any better? Instead of `append` use `add`.

Comment: realized first response was kinda lacking---I need a list of the function but with 15 different exponents and the unique remainder to simply print only the number of the unique remainders for that change so I end up with 15 rows. The p,q, and diminished are parts of the original program previously written in class, so that shouldn't change anywhere expect maybe placement as far as I know.

Comment: No change in how it's printing, still the multi listing for the unique_remainders for e instead of just the length. Is it perhaps how i'm doing my e in range?

Comment: Could you please delcare `unique_remainders_list = set()` before the for loops begin? Or have you done it already?

Comment: I've tried adding the list before but I basically get  only 12 and 13 and unique listing 1-35 instead

Comment: I am not sure if your ranges are okay. Syntatically, the script is correct.

Comment: Hmm, I've tried placing the range of e before and after the list and placing the range for e after x gives way to big of answers. A friends of mine couldn't see what I was doing wrong exactly either, which was why I decided to try here.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, needed to move my print statement over. I hate when I miss such small things, but thanks for the help hagubear.

```
for e in range(12,27):
 unique_remainders_list = []
 for x in range(1,(n+1)):
 y = x**e % n
 diminished = (p - 1)*(q - 1)
 gcd = greatest_common_divisor(e, diminished)
 max_uni_val = n-1
 if not (y in unique_remainders_list):
    unique_remainders_list.append(y)
 print("{:>2} {:>4} {:>6} {:>4} {:>10} {:>9} {:>10} {:>16}".\
format(p,q,n,e,diminished,gcd,len(unique_remainders_list),max_uni_val, end = ' '))
```